# How to convert a curl url to POSTMAN Request

Tags: json, postman

I have a curl link which is `successfully run with terminal` but i want to convert it as a POSTMAN request where link is,

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -u ApiUserAdmin:1234 http://10.20.10.50/API/TaskHandle -d "{\"event\":\"evening\",\"wish\":\"Good Evening\"}" &
```

and when i import it it gives ,

> Error while importing Curl: 2 option-less arguments found. Only one is supported (the URL)
> and when i convert it in mannually like,
> [image]
> and header is like
> [image]

Then it gives error,
[image]

> How to i solve the ApiUserAdmin and password.
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're putting the username/password in the wrong section. Move it from the Header tab on Postman to the Authorization tab. Try selecting "Basic Auth" from the Type dropdown and putting the username/password in the fields that show up.

Comment: Oh Dear, thanks For quick reply. i set `Basic Auth` and its Work. Thanks Again.